# SQL: Need to SUM column for each type

Tags: sql

How can I find the SUM of all scores for the minimum date of each lesson_id please:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|id |uid |group_id |lesson_id |game_id |score |date       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|1  |145 |1        |1         |0       |40    |1391627323 |
|2  |145 |1        |1         |0       |80    |1391627567 |
|3  |145 |1        |2         |0       |40    |1391627323 |
|4  |145 |1        |3         |0       |30    |1391627323 |
|5  |145 |1        |3         |0       |90    |1391627567 |
|6  |145 |1        |4         |0       |20    |1391628000 |
|7  |145 |1        |5         |0       |35    |1391628000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I need output:

```
-------------------
|sum_first_scores |
-------------------
|165              |
-------------------
```

I have this so far, which lists the score for each minimum date, per lesson, but I need to sum those results as above:

```
SELECT lesson_id, MIN(date), score AS first_score FROM cdu_user_progress 
WHERE cdu_user_progress.uid = 145
GROUP BY lesson_id
```

Comment: did you not try SUM(score) then ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Select SUM(first_score) as sum_first_scores from (SELECT lesson_id, MIN(date), score AS first_score FROM cdu_user_progress 
WHERE cdu_user_progress.uid = 145
GROUP BY lesson_id)

Comment: In your SQL are you sure it is working (SELECT lesson_id, MIN(date), score)  I don't see how score could participate in the result without being in the group by the same way lesson_id is.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the first score as the one where no earlier record exists.  Then just take the sum:

```
select sum(score)
from edu_user_progress eup
where cdu_user_progress.uid = 145 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from edu_user_progress eup2
                  where eup2.uid = eup.uid and
                        eup2.lesson_id = eup.lesson_id and
                        eup2.date < eup.date
                 );
```

This assumes that the minimum date for the lesson id has only one score.

Comment: Analytic SQL should be useful for this query: SUM(score) OVER (PARTITION BY lesion_id ORDER BY date)

Comment: @jbaliuka . . . There are actually many ways to write this query, although that doesn't happen to be one of them.  Window/analytic functions are definitely a possibility.  The above will work in the largest number of databases (note that the OP has not specified a database).

Comment: MySQL 7, but I couldn't get your analytic query to work: SELECT SUM(score) OVER (PARTITION BY lesion_id ORDER BY date) FROM cdu_user_progress

Comment: Can you please add example with analytic query, it is more interesting because it should perform better and most of modern databases already support it (Oracle,SQl Server,PostgreSQl,MySQL)

Comment: I do not have MySQL on my machine to test it, looks like all of articles I saw about MySQL and analytic is just emulation

Comment: @jbaliuka . . . I think the `not exists` version of the query will actually perform better on most databases than a version with analytic functions.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I did not use Oracle analytic functions because SQL Server did not support but latest release supports it and started to rewrite my queries, all of them are much faster with large tables because normally DB just sorts rows by index and there is no correlation but looks like it is irrelevant for MySQL anyways.